# monkey patch not working properly

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, monkeypatching

So I'm running py.test and trying to use monkeypatch. I understand that monkeypatch's intended purpose is to replace attributes in a module so that they can be tested. And I get that we can substitute in mock functions in order to do this.

Currently I am trying to run essentially the following block of code.

```
from src.module.submodule import *

def mock_function(parameter = None):
    return 0

def test_function_works(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr("src.module.submodule.function",mock_function ]
   assert function(parameter = None) == 0
```

When the test runs, instead of swapping in `mock_function`, it just runs `function` . Could there be a reason why monkeypatch isn't activating

I have got monkey patch running succesfully with other code before. So I don't see why this isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used pytest for this stuff, but I know that with the `mock` library, functions are patched in the namespace where they're called. i.e. `from src.module.submodule import *` imports `src.module.submodule.function` into your namespace, but you then patch it in its original namespace, so your local name for the function still accesses the original, unpatched code.

If you change this to

```
import src.module.submodule

def mock_function(parameter = None):
    return 0

def test_function_works(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr("src.module.submodule.function",mock_function ]
    assert src.module.submodule.function(parameter = None) == 0
```

does it succeed?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo, shouldn't it be

```
 monkeypatch.setattr("src.module.submodule.function",mockIfunction)
```

i.e. `mockIfunction` instead of `mock_function`?

Comment: these are all fake filenames so ignore typos. I can't post actual work code

Comment: But presumably the `mockIfunction` and `mock_function` should match, otherwise what are you mocking your function with?